# How to display a single Windows Explorer folder (that cannot be navigated away from) within a userform?

Tags: vb.net

I would like to have a box within the userform display the contents of a single folder.

I would like the folder to display icons similar to how Windows Explorer does, and I would also like users to be able to drag icons from other windows into it (just like a real explorer window).

I decided to use a listview, and this will populate it with a bunch of lines of text for each file, but clicking on them does nothing and I cannot drag anything in. Also they don't have icons.

Any ideas?

```
Dim fileEntries As String() = Directory.GetFiles("C:\Windows\")
For Each fileName As String In fileEntries
    ListView1.Items.Add(fileName)
Next
```

Comment: This is programming after all. If "clicking" does nothing, you have to add code to specify what you want the clicking to do. This is accomplished through events. To drag and drop, you need to handle those associated events. Here's an article to get you started. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/307966

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404308%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) describes exactly how to do this.  it even gets the icons, as you requested!  It also uses a ListView, too! Enjoy!

As Jeremy said, you will still need to hook up event, if you want it to respond to click (or drag) events.

```
Private listView1 As ListView
Private imageList1 As ImageList


Public Sub ExtractAssociatedIconEx()

    ' Initialize the ListView, ImageList and Form.
    listView1 = New ListView()
    imageList1 = New ImageList()
    listView1.Location = New Point(37, 12)
    listView1.Size = New Size(161, 242)
    listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1
    listView1.View = View.SmallIcon
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(292, 266)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.listView1)
    Me.Text = "Form1"

    ' Get the c:\ directory.
    Dim dir As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\")

    Dim item As ListViewItem
    listView1.BeginUpdate()
    Dim file As System.IO.FileInfo
    For Each file In dir.GetFiles()

        ' Set a default icon for the file.
        Dim iconForFile As Icon = SystemIcons.WinLogo

        item = New ListViewItem(file.Name, 1)

        ' Check to see if the image collection contains an image
        ' for this extension, using the extension as a key.
        If Not (imageList1.Images.ContainsKey(file.Extension)) Then

            ' If not, add the image to the image list.
            iconForFile = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(file.FullName)
            imageList1.Images.Add(file.Extension, iconForFile)
        End If
        item.ImageKey = file.Extension
        listView1.Items.Add(item)

    Next file
    listView1.EndUpdate()
End Sub
```

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.